# Is it safe to use photon-resin-calibration for Epax printer?

Tags: resin, dlp

This repository contains a calibration test for DLP printers.

As its file [`Instructions.txt`](https://github.com/altLab/photon-resin-calibration/blob/master/resin-xp-finder/Instructions.txt) says, it is an `ANYCUBIC RESIN EXPOSURE FINDER by X3msnake`.

Are all the files, both `.photon` and `.gcode`, compatible with the Epax X1 printer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems to be.

I tried the test and it worked well.

Comment: Hi stenci and welcome to SE.3DP. I'm glad that you proved the case. Please don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer, using the (green) tick icon next to your answer. That will remove your queue from our unanswered queue list. Thanks in advance. You *might* have to wait 24 hours though, before you can see the tick icon...

Comment: Please explain the test in the answer, as that would make this answer much better. SLA and DLP are things many in the community have little experience with, so any information you propagate your experience and how you acquire it can help others perform the same tests to check if their resin is compatible with their printer.